# display html formatted text in android app

Tags: android

I am porting a web application to android platform.The app will consist of some web content (accessed using `WebView`) and some offline content. I need to display some amount of text as offline content in the home screen, and I'm kinda confused how to go about it. I have gone through the android documentation of formatting text, but I found it a bit tedious to use when dealing with more than a few lines of text. So I am considering creating some HTML pages and including them in the res folder of my app. And then loading them using `WebView`. Is it advisable to use such an approach? or is there a better way out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well for simple text you can always do following on a `TextView`:

```
someTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlAsAString));
```

If as you say it is more complicated (with images and/or css etc.) I'd recommend putting the html in the assets/ folder and load it from there directly into a `WebView`.

Answer (score 4):

There's the `Html` class which can format HTML text but it's quite limited.
You can read the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

The method that you'll probably be most interested in is `Html.fromHtml(java.lang.String)`. It returns an `Spanned` object which you can then use to populate a `TextView` by simply calling `textView.setText(..)`.

If you find that it does not provide the required support for the HTML tags that you need then you'll most likely end up using a `WebView`.

Comment: yeah I have tried `Html.fromHtml()` but it only supports a very limited number of HTML tags